# Splitting recursive groups

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in this format:
`a,b,c[a,b,c[a]],d`

And what (in the end) I want to end up with, is

```
a
b
c.a
c.b
c.c.a
d
```

Any suggestion on how to approach this task?

Comment: Probably easier (and more likely to be possible) without regex.

Comment: This is not a regex stuff. Parse it yourself.

Comment: Sounds like you might need a custom linked list. For example when you get to "c", that would be the head, and then a/b/c would be next node. So you'd have some thing like c->a, c->b, c->c->a. Regardless, it's a challenging question.

Comment: regex can't do this. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using stack. (Implemented Avlin Bunk's comment.)

```
public static Iterable<String> split(String s) {
    List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[,\\[\\]]|.+?");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    stack.push("");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String token = matcher.group();
        if (token.equals("[")) {
            stack.push("");
        } else if (token.equals("]")) {
            if (! stack.peek().isEmpty())
                result.add(join(".", stack));
            stack.pop();
            stack.pop();
            stack.push("");
        } else if (token.equals(",")) {
            if (! stack.peek().isEmpty())
                result.add(join(".", stack));
        } else {
            stack.pop();
            stack.push(token);
        }
    }
    if (! (stack.isEmpty() || stack.peek().isEmpty()))
        result.add(join(".", stack));
    return result;
}
```

---

```
public static String join(String sep, Iterable<String> it) {
    // Return it[0] + sep + it[1] + sep + .... + it[lastIndex]
    String joined = "";
    boolean first = true;

    for (String s : it) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            joined += sep;
        joined += s;
    }
    return joined;
}
```

Example Usage:

```
String text = "a,b,c[a,b,c[a]],d";
for (String s : split(text))
    System.out.println(s);
```

See [Demo run](http://ideone.com/ObBMQ8).

([Same solution in Python](http://ideone.com/ICDakP), [Recursive solution in Python](http://ideone.com/wywzXl))